# How can I inprove my render image quality, even used denoiser too

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, denoise

I have used denoiser, resoluton 1080x1080 px, render300, but still image looks blury when I zoomed it in.

[image]

Comment: Hi, what settings are you using for the render? How many samples?

Answer (score 2):

The resolution and the amount of samples you used are not particularly high. The simple answer is: if you want more quality, you should increase the resolution and samples. If you tried something like 4096x4096 resolution and 2000 samples, the image will become a lot clearer.

You will of course inevitably face exactly the same issue almost every single one of us face pretty much constantly - your render times will increase dramatically. There is a solution to that none of 3d artists like to hear about - just buy better/more hardware, or use render farms. SheepIt is great for example, because it's free in a sense you do not need to pay money, but you still need good hardware to constantly render projects of other people so you collect points and can get yours rendered quickly when you need it.

Comment: Hi Martynas.

Could you please share your PC specs, I'd like to make a new PC within the year, and I'm always keen on learning what specs would be good for 3D.

Thank you.

Comment: Hi, I cannot recommend what I am using, the hardware is outdated, but I do not use my PCs for rendering so it works for me. Try asking for help at Blenderartists.org, I am sure somebody will recommend you something more up to date and more according your needs that would not be practical to discuss here.